# where can i start from basic sql query and become expert in that?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Please help me in this, I know only basic queries in sql, and where can I start from sql query and become expert in that?
What are all the steps to follow and books to learn?

Comment: [Google is your friend...](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To become good in what you do, you have to like what you do.
[google how to become oracle guru](http://www.google.nl/search?q=how%20to%20become%20oracle%20guru)
If you like what you do, you are most likely to spend lots of time learning things by experimenting and making many errors. From errors we learn.... (happens to be my blog name)

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle db, see [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/toc.htm).  You'll want to learn as much ansi SQL as you can, but each db will have features that you'll want to exploit as well.

Comment: +1.  If you want to be good at Oracle SQL then you need to bookmark that link and use it all the time, even before Google.  For example, your previous question would have been best answered by searching that page for ROWID.

Answer (score 0):

[You can follow this very good step-by-step guide](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/SQLDeveloper/index.htm)